# After javaScript dynamically added some tags to my HTML my design changed as it is, how do i fix this proplem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have HTML with table and select option element, when user changes selection the JavaScript adds additional row to the table but the design and the feel of the table also gets changed.

this is my code

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="POITable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>S.No</th>
            <th>Item Description</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="odd grade">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>
                <select name="project_no" class="form-control" onchange="insRow()" style="border-color: #fff; width:100%;">
                    <option value="all">Select Project No</option>
                    <option value="1">466</option>
                    <option value="2">566</option>
                    <option value="3">101</option>
                    <option value="all">all</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" style="border-color: #fff; width:50px;" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

```
function deleteRow(row) {
    var i = row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById('POITable').deleteRow(i);
}


function insRow() {
    console.log('hi');
    var x = document.getElementById('POITable');
    var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
    var len = x.rows.length;
    new_row.cells[0].innerHTML = len;
    var inp1 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
    inp1.id += len;
    inp1.value = '';
    var inp2 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp2.id += len;
    inp2.value = '';
    x.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].appendChild(new_row);
}
```

my desing firstly looks like this:
[image: my desing firstly looks like this:]

and when gets dynamic information it will looks like this:

[image: and when gets dynamic information it will looks like this]

Comment: Do an inspect element on the table and find the differences in the rows/cells.

Comment: Please provide the CSS for the table or create jsfiddle in order us to help you.

Comment: Your new rows are being appended after <tbody>. They need to be inside <tbody> element.

Comment: the only difference is, that the first row will close the tbody tag </tbody>.

Comment: Yes, Mr. @WhatisSober that is the main problem i saw in inspect element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should append to the `<tbody>` element, not the `<table>` element itself. Instead of

```
x.appendChild( new_row );
```

you could use

```
document.querySelector('tbody').appendChild( new_row );
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/kwg85z7e/**

if there is more than one table on the page you must use a more explicit selector -> `document.querySelector('#POITable tbody').appendChild( new_row );`

Comment: by `querySelector("tbody")`, do you mean `getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0]`?

Comment: @Saedawke - Thank you for accepting the answer. Use `document.querySelector('#POITable tbody').appendChild( new_row );` to target the `#POITable tbody` explicitly.

Comment: @JanDvorak, no, I mean `querySelector`. Just by looking at `getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0]` it should be clear to anyone why  the easy `querySelector`  that returns 1 result is preferable.

Comment: @davidkonrad, i used  `x`  variable which i was declared earlier as   `document.getElementById('POITable');`

Answer (score 1):

You are adding new fields outside of tbody.

```
 function insRow() {
    console.log('hi');
    var x = document.getElementById('POITable');
    var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
    var len = x.rows.length;
    new_row.cells[0].innerHTML = len;
    var inp1 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
    inp1.id += len;
    inp1.value = '';
    var inp2 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp2.id += len;
    inp2.value = '';
    x.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].appendChild(new_row);
}
```

Jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/usyze4s0/2/

Answer (score 0):

Change `x.appendChild( new_row );` with `x.querySelector('tbody').appendChild( new_row );`